# Django: how to access indirect values within a model, two levels down

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to access a list of values two levels down in a model to be displayed in a template.

In the below model, you have a shopping basket within which you can put different kinds of meat.

Assume you now have put two types of meat in your shopping basket, Ribeye, and Rump steak, what level of protein has each of the two types got?

My models looks like this:

```
class ShopOrder(models.Model):
    order_date = models.DateField()
    meatbasket = models.ManyToManyField('food.Meat', blank=True)

# App food
class Meat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    nutrition  =  models.OneToOneField(Nutrition, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Nutrition(models.Model):
    protein = models.IntegerField()
    fat = models.IntegerField()
```

I have no problem to create a list on the first level down (list of 'meat' names from the Model 'Meat' below:

```
meat_names  = list(object.meatbasket.values_list('name', flat=True))
```

However, how do I access the next level down, i.e. in my example to get number of 'protein' for each Meat name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a queryset approach your can use a '__' to access fields that span relationsships. This is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) in the docs.

In your case this could be something like

```
prot_values = shoppingorder.meatbasket.values_list('name', 'nutrition__protein')
```

returning all the meat names and associated protein values in your shoppingorder.

Comment: Brilliant, I could not have found this without your help

Answer (score 1):

Here is the plain Python code that return/print the `protein` value from **`ShopOrder`** model

```
for shop_order in ShopOrder.objects.all():
    for meat in shop_order.meatbasket.all():
        print(meat.nutrition.protein)
```

You can do the same in Django template also, by using [**`for` loop**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

```
{% for shop_order in shop_order_qs %}
    {% for meat in shop_order.meatbasket.all %}
        Meat Name: {{ meat.name }}
        Protein: {{ meat.nutrition.protein }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The **`shop_order_qs`** is the **context variable** that hold the value of **`ShopOrder.objects.all()`** or ***`ShopOrder` QuerySet***